# How to add slider for google map info card in ionic 3

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

i am very new to ionic framework. I want to add  multiple markers along with the information card in the slider form just like the image attached with this .
I have able to add multiple  markers in the map but no idea how to add information slider  which will activate the marker. corresponding  to the slider.
Can any please give me some hint on how to work with this.

My eventmap.ts file to show multiple markers

```
export class EventMapPage {
    public userToken:any;
    public userPostData = {"api_token":""};
    public responseData:any;
    public dataSet:any;



    @ViewChild('map') mapRef:ElementRef;

  constructor(...) {
      this.getEvents().then(result=> {
          this.responseData = result;
          this.DisplayMap(this.responseData);
      });

  }

     //Get all the available events
    getEvents(){
        const data = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
        this.userPostData.api_token= data;
        return this.authService.postData(this.userPostData,'events');
    }

    //Initializing the map


  DisplayMap(data) {
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
   const location = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude,
     resp.coords.longitude);
   const options = {
     center:location,
     zoom:10,
     mapTypeControl: false,
     streetViewControl:false,
   };
     const map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement,options);
     //Loop the markers
       if(data != null){
         for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
           this.multipleMaker(parseFloat(data[i].lat),parseFloat(data[i].lon),map);
         }
       }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });

  }

  //Marker function
 multipleMaker(lat,lng,map) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position:{lat:lat,lng:lng},
        map:map
    });
}


}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi this will be quite hard but definitely possiable. Just so I understand this correctly, sliding the bottom slider will change the address thus changing the corresponding marker colour.

Comment: Hi yes, sliding bottom slider will change the address and it will change the marker color corresponding to that slider and make the maker as the center of the map

Comment: Sweet, could you include the code for you making the map and adding markers

Comment: @YusofBandar hi, i added the  my code to show multiple markers on the map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some trail an error , research on google, i finally figured it out .

The solution to this that i come up with is as follows

in map.html

```
<ion-content >
  <div #map id="map">
  </div>

  <div  class="slider-wraper">
    <ion-slides slidesPerView="1" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()">
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of responseData?.weekEvents">
        <ion-card tappable (click)="viewDetail(item.id)">
          <div class="event-image-holder search-list">
            <img src="http://localhost:8000/{{item.photo_url}}"/>
          </div>
          <ion-card-content>
            <div class="event-info">
              <div class="event-descp">
                <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
                <p>
                  {{item.club.name}}
                </p>
                <p>
                  <strong>{{item.attendees.length}} are going</strong>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

in map.ts

First import slider

```
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Then inside class get the reference of the slider

```
@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;
```

Then add this methord

```
slideChanged() {
    let currentIndex = this.slides.getActiveIndex();
    let currentEvent  =this.responseData.weekEvents[currentIndex];
    this.map.setCenter({lat: parseFloat(currentEvent.lat),lng:parseFloat(currentEvent.lon)});
}
```

This will make the marker of current slider as the center of the map

Only thing now left to do is clicking on marker should make the slider active.
I will update it here once its done. :))